# Transition CSS pseudo element

Tags: css, transition, pseudo-element

I can't seem to get my pseudo element to ease on hover. I'm not sure what's wrong with my CSS. I cannot change the HTML since it's in Drupal. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ecupaio/anq9pr04/3/)

```css
.portfolio-image {
  position: relative;
  background: none;  
}
.portfolio-image a {
    background: none;
}
.portfolio-image:hover a:before {
  content: "\f002";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 25%;
  padding-left: 45%;
  font-size: 5em;
  line-height: 0em;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: 0.7s ease;
  -webkit-transition: 0.7s ease;
  -moz-transition: 0.7s ease;
}
.portfolio-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
}
```

```html
     <div width="500px";> <div class="portfolio-image"><a href="http://iTreeLessons.com"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://staging.edcupaioli.com/sites/default/files/Home%20%20%20iTree%20Lesson%20Plans.png" alt="" height="705" width="1280"></a></div>    </div>
```

Comment: why you cannot change the HTML, if it is in Drupal?

Comment: And what's wrong with `.portfolio-image:hover`? https://jsfiddle.net/rxjacssg/

Comment: what should be actually animated? You don't have an initial state to animate from. Create the pseudo-before-element without hover first, and on hover put only changed values

Comment: simon: the background and content (transparent black overlay and the icon) should ease in on hover.

Comment: sjagr: your solution does not work. the overlay stays in place and the image goes off somewhere else.

Comment: simon: tried that, but to no avail [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ecupaio/anq9pr04/6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. smnbbrv was right on creating the pseudo element without the hover first, then adding the transition. I made the pseudo element have an opacity of 0 to make it hidden, then invoked a opacity of 1 on hover with the transition affect.

```css
.portfolio-image {
  position: relative;
}
.portfolio-image a:before {
  content: "\f14c";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  position: absolute;
  color: yellow;
  padding-top: 25%;
  padding-left: 45%;
  font-size: 5em;
  line-height: 0em;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  opacity: 0;
}
.portfolio-image a:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
}
.portfolio-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-image">
  <a href="http://symantecinnovationawards.com/">
    <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://staging.edcupaioli.com/sites/default/files/Award%20Details%20%20%20Symantec%20Innovation%20Awards.png" width="1280" height="626" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```